# Mongodb "readWrite" role not allowing to read data from collection - nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, roles

I have created application using mongodb+nodejs

I have added new user with following roles in mongodb

```
{
        "_id" : "testdb.testdbuser",
        "user" : "testdbuser",
        "db" : "testdb",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "testdb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "testdb"
                }
        ]
}
```

Started server using `--auth` option.
And also started node application using mongodb user credentials.

But, I am not able to read data from `user` collection in `testdb` database.

Getting this error : 
`MongoError: not authorized for query on testdb.user`

Please any suggestion? Anything I am missing?

Comment: are you using mongodb via mlab or via localhost created way?

Comment: I am using mongodb via localhost

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the read role to the user testdbuser.

testsdbuser role does not include read access on non-system collections.
You can give it like this, it seems,

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
    "testdbuser",
    [
      { role: "read", db: "testdb" }
    ]
)
```

Comment: can you please upvote and mark this post complete then?